# How do i pass the web method to the label

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

`enter code here`I got difficulty to pass the web method to the label. I also using the sql to pass the information to the label.Can u all help me?

This is my web method.

```
 public string[] GetCPname(string cpname)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\\Temp\\StudentsDatabase.mdb");
            conn.Open();

            //Get the ID of the selected book.
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM Student where Name = @name", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", cpname);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            int cpNameID = reader.GetInt32(0);

            //Get all the reviews with the Book_ID selected.
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT CPname FROM StudentInformation where ID = @id", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cpNameID);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
            // Disconnect from DB
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            // Convert ArrayList to string array and return
            return result.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
        }



 This is my coding to pass to the label.


 protected void retrievecpname(string CP)
        {

            StudentsWSRef.StudentsWS ws = new StudentsWSRef.StudentsWS();
            string[] x = ws.GetStudentNames();
            lblcpName.Text = CP;

        }
```

I got problem with this code as it still did not pass the information to the label.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to pass to the label ? You cannot pass a method. You can only set the properties that you want.

Comment: Where did you call "retrievecpname" function? i coudn't find it in your code

Comment: I dont understand this code, what do you do with `x` inside `retrievecpname`?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the Question is full or not?? In this method retrievecpname you are simply call the WebService Method, adn Set Some Cp variable to Label. I couldn't get what you are trying to say. GetCPname returns the String[], to change the text of Label we have to just assign some string to .Text property.